# Can't get output to not be null

Tags: swing, groovy

I'm trying to make a really simple text input field (to replicate later for a more complex purpose). Using IDEA 14 CE, not sure it matters. I wrote this code:

```
import groovy.swing.SwingBuilder
import groovy.beans.Bindable
import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE
import java.awt.*

String word

@Bindable
class UserInput {
    String word
    //String toString() { "$word" }
}

def userInput = new UserInput(word: null)

def swingBuilder = new SwingBuilder()
    swingBuilder.edt {
    lookAndFeel 'nimbus'
    // frame size
    def width = 350
    def height = 230
    frame (
            title: 'Input',
            size: [width, height],
            show: true,
            locationRelativeTo: null,
            defaultCloseOperation: EXIT_ON_CLOSE ) {
        borderLayout(vgap: 5)
        panel(constraints:
                BorderLayout.CENTER,
                border: compoundBorder([emptyBorder(10), titledBorder('Input:')]))
        {
            tableLayout {
                tr {
                    td { label 'Input: ' }
                    td { textField userInput.word, id: userInput.word, columns: 20 }
                }
            }
        }
        panel(constraints: BorderLayout.SOUTH) {
            button text: 'Print word', actionPerformed: {
                println """Word: ${userInput.word}"""
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run it, I get this Swing box:

[image: box]

No matter what I input, when I click <kbd>Print Word</kbd> it always prints:

> ```
> Word: null
> ```

What am I doing wrong? Seems like I am failing to assign user input to a parameter or something like that, but I cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right, you need to use bean binding to get the text property of the textField bound to your model.  This works:

```
import groovy.swing.SwingBuilder
import groovy.beans.Bindable
import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE
import java.awt.*

String word

@Bindable
class UserInput {
    String word
}

def userInput = new UserInput(word: null)

def swingBuilder = new SwingBuilder().edt {
    lookAndFeel 'nimbus'
    // frame size
    def width = 350
    def height = 230
    frame (title: 'Input',
           size: [width, height],
           show: true,
           locationRelativeTo: null ) {
        borderLayout(vgap: 5)
        panel(constraints: BorderLayout.CENTER,
              border: compoundBorder([emptyBorder(10), titledBorder('Input:')])) {
            tableLayout {
                tr {
                    td { label 'Input: ' }
                    td { textField id:'input', columns: 20 }
                }
            }
        }
        panel(constraints: BorderLayout.SOUTH) {
            button text: 'Print word', actionPerformed: {
                println """Word: ${userInput.word}"""
            }
        }
        // Bind the text field to the bean
        bean userInput, word: bind { input.text }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also see. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6349107/groovy-swingbuilder-bind-to-multiple-properties

Comment: No that did not make any difference

Comment: Try moving `Bindable` from the class to the `word` field

Comment: I'll try and get on a computer to test  ;-)

Comment: Updated after actually trying it on a computer ;-)

Comment: Glad to help! Soz for the initial fumble ;-)

Comment: Don't mean to be a bother, but, given appropriate #NamingThings this can be extended to multiple fields right?

Comment: No problems, not sure I get you though. You mean bind multiple things to multiple fields? Yeah you can keep adding `fieldname: bind { uielementid.property }` map elements to the `bean` call

Comment: I was planning on binding the input values to params i can pass to a DB, but I'll ask another question if I run into problems

Comment: Cool, that sounds doable, good luck! :-) groovy is great for ui stuff